# $\exp(i\alpha\hat {\bf n}\cdot{\bf \sigma} )=\cos\alpha I+i(\hat {\bf n}\cdot{\bf \sigma})\sin\alpha$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, notation, linear-algebra

[image: I don't understand this proof]

Could anyone tell me $\hat {\bf n}\cdot{\bf \sigma}$ is defined in such way? In the book they have not defined what is $n_z,n_x,n_y$.

It is from *Quantum Computing: From Linear Algebra to Physical Realization* by Nakahara, First Chapter, page 23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, $\mathbf{n}$ is a unit vector and $n_x$, $n_y$ and $n_z$ are its cartesian components. $\mathbf{n}$ is just a vector pointing in an arbitrarily direction with magnitude 1. Taking $\mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{\sigma}$, we have
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{\sigma} = n_x\sigma_x + n_y \sigma_y + n_z \sigma_z \\
= n_x \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\1&0\end{array}\right) + n_y \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & -i\\i&0\end{array}\right) + n_z \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\0&-1\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks but why Eigen Values of $A$ are $\pm1$?If $n=({1\over \sqrt{2}},{1\over\sqrt{2}},0)$ then $n_x=({1\over\sqrt{2}},0,0),n_y=(0,{1\over\sqrt{2}},0),n_z=(0,0,0)$ ?

Comment: And also $n_x,n_y,n_z$ are $1\times 3$ matrices and pauli matrcies are $2\times 2$ then why $n_x\sigma_x$ etc are defined?

Comment: In fact $n_x$, $n_y$ and $n_z$ are just numbers --- the collection of the three of them together is the vector $\mathbf{n}$. The notation is possibly a little bit confusing, but the equation defining $A$ is the dot product of a vector of numbers, $\mathbf{n} = (n_x, n_y, n_z)$, and a vector of matrices, $\boldsymbol \sigma$ $= (\sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z)$.

Comment: To find the eigenvalues of $A$, we take $|A - \lambda \mathbb{1}|=0$, which gives $-(n_z - \lambda)(n_z + \lambda) - (n_x + i n_y)(n_x - i n_y)=0$ or equivalently $\lambda^2 = n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2$. Since $\mathbf{n}$ is a unit vector, the right hand side is 1 and we get $\lambda^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

What you really want to know are the definitions of the $\sigma_i$ --- these are the [Pauli matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices):

$$ \sigma_x = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \qquad \sigma_y = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix} \qquad \sigma_z = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Hopefully you can see now how the equation follows.